# post data in meteorjs when using curl

Tags: http, post, curl, meteor

I have the following method to post data to server :

```
 curl --ipv4  http://localhost:3000/api/tests/1 -d @test.csv
```

I am trying to post a file with curl to a meter app

In meteor I am not able to read the data because I cant attach a key to the curl option data arrives as the key itself

example

```
contents of test.csv  = > 1,1,1
```

at server

```
console.log('route to host' , this.request.body); yields {{1,1,1} : ''}
```

And yes I even tried -F data=@test.csv with no success as well

How can I add a key and make the contents of the file as value when posting through curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works!!

```
curl --ipv4 --data-urlencode  "csv@test.csv"  http://localhost:3000/api/tests/1
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: I cant I have to wait two days. IF you can mark it as correct that would be very helpful :)

Comment: only the person that asked the question can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

basically -d for curl means read the file and use its content as data

> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named 'foobar' would thus be done with --data @foobar. When --data is told to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out. If you don't want the @ character to have a special interpretation use --data-raw instead.

in order to send the file itself youll need something like -F

> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.
>
> Example, to send your password file to the server, where 'password' is
>   the name of the form-field to which /etc/passwd will be the input:
>
> curl -F password=@/etc/passwd www.mypasswords.com

in your case probably use -F
curl --ipv4  http://localhost:3000/api/tests/1 -F data=

if you want to file to be uploaded as a file use -F data=@test.csv